# WFFM sitecore 8.2 initial release on Content Delivery Server

Tags: wffm, sitecore-client

I upgraded WFFM to 8.2 initial release. After applying all changes, when I open the form I get the following error:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not create instance of the Sitecore.Forms.Core.Handlers.FormDataHandler class.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: Could not create instance of the Sitecore.Forms.Core.Handlers.FormDataHandler class.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[Exception: Could not create instance of the Sitecore.Forms.Core.Handlers.FormDataHandler class.]
   Sitecore.WFFM.Abstractions.Dependencies.DependenciesManager.Resolve(String path) +263
   Sitecore.Form.Core.Ascx.Controls.SimpleForm..ctor() +26
   Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.SitecoreSimpleForm..ctor(Item item) +21
   Sitecore.Form.Core.Renderings.FormRender.OnInit(EventArgs e) +349
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +166
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +379
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +379
   System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +379
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1839

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1087.0

Any idea what would be the issue or is something missing?

Thanks,

Comment: WFFM dlls missing on your CD server?

Comment: There were 8 dlls in the upgrade.. all were copied to the CD server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore.Marketing.config file was missing in the include folder of the content delivery server..when i added it, everything worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

It seems DependencyPathAttribute's Path is empty from your exception log

1.Are you missing any CD environment specific config/patch up ?
2.Also please make sure 'Sitecore.WFFM.Dependencies.config' is enabled.
3.From 8.1+ versions WFFM allows configuration driven dependency injection i.e. Constructor parameters can be handled through the params defined in config 
. More details here please
[Injecting dependencies into a custom WFFM save action](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/injecting-dependencies-into-a-custom-wffm-save-action)

Please specific your old WFFM version.

Comment: Where can I find this DependencyPathAttribute's Path? I did copy all config files and dlls for the CD environment. I don't have any custom actions so I don't think the link you sent me regarding the save action would resolve the issue right since that i don't have any custom action?

Comment: Could you please let us know your wffm old version. There are few breaking changes in 8.1 + versions

Comment: I upgraded from 8.1 Update 2 to 8.1 Update 3 then to 8.2 initial release

Comment: can you compare your WFFM related CD config files with 8.2 https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/3C23956B4C2A455B9E13B900EE01A188.ashx