# WFFM upgrade - Where is the EmailSender class in 8.2?

Tags: wffm, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade some code from 7.2 to 8.2 and there are some custom mail actions in the codebase. I've tracked down most of the other stuff to its equivalent in the new namespaces, but I'm having difficulty finding the equivalent of the old `Sitecore.Form.Submit.EmailSender` class.

Does anybody know which namespace this is in now?

Comment: I assume this is the "Send Email" Save Action? So maybe you want `Sitecore.WFFM.Actions.SaveActions.SendMessage, Sitecore.WFFM.Actions`? [Sitecore 8.1+ allows for dependency injection](http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/injecting-dependencies-into-a-custom-wffm-save-action/1680#1680) of Save Actions so it defined in configuration now.

Comment: Thank you @jammykam, can you convert to answer? That class does look like it has what I need for doing a direct port of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WFFM module was been significantly refactored in Sitecore 8.1+ and [now allows for configuration driven dependency injection](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1672/injecting-dependencies-into-a-custom-wffm-save-action/1680#1680). The old Send Email Save Action has now been changed to `Sitecore.WFFM.Actions.SaveActions.SendMessage` in **Sitecore.WFFM.Actions.dll**.

The `Factory Object Name` field in the `Send Email Message` item is now set to the following:

[image: Send Email Message]

The setting points to a configuration node, which is defined in **Sitecore.WFFM.Dependencies.config**.

```
<sendMessage type="Sitecore.WFFM.Actions.SaveActions.SendMessage, Sitecore.WFFM.Actions">
  <param name="settings" ref="/sitecore/wffm/settings" />
  <param name="mailSender" ref="/sitecore/wffm/mailSender" />
</sendMessage>
```

The Save Action is carried out by the class specified in the type attribute.

Note that the constructor and method signatures have also changed since earlier versions so you will need to refactor your code but the change is not significant.

Comment: Thank you @jammykam! I had already refactored to use the SendMessage class as my mapping but wasn't sure it was the right one since the constructor had changed. Thank you for confirming!